# how to enable side area of my website in mobile responsive view in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web, themes

I need to change the mobile responsive view of my site.I want my side bar to be displayed in the mobile view.

How to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Write a `media query` in your `CSS` one that shows the `<div>` on views smaller then `...px` and one that hides the `<div>` bigger then `...px`. You can use the example below

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    div.sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    div.sidebar {
        display: block;
    }
}
```